# Is there a mathematical symbol for "once"?

Tags: notation

I've found a couple symbols that include the concept of once, like "the list of values which appear only once" and stuff like that. Is there a symbol that just means "once" or "one repetition" or "single"? Like, "f() happens one time." (sorry if the combinatorics tag is off-base. I wanted to just use "symbols" but couldn't find a tag like that)

Comment: I replaced the combinatorics tag with the notation tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\exists!P(x)$ is defined to mean that there is only one occurrence where $P(x)$ is true.

It is called [uniqueness quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification)

Comment: Usually "read" as "there exists unique $x$".

Comment: That seems to be the closest to what the OP means. For all other usages of the word "once", one should not that it is certainly better to just use a concise and understandable natural language description with the word "once" than to introduce an obscure notation

Comment: To be precise, the definition should read "there is one and only one", as "there is only one" could mean "there is zero or one "

Comment: Yeah, but doesn't that mean that P(x) happens a lot and one of the happenings will be true, not that P(x) happens one time?

Comment: It would help a lot if you gave context to your question. What exactly do you want to write in mathematical terms?

Comment: @Matt In what sense do you intend "$P(x)$ happens" and "$P(x)$ is true" to be different? (This should be clarified in the question).